# Find maximum Y in JavaFX XYSeries

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

```
series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(x ,function(x));
```

I try to get maximum of function(x); I know I can use "series.getData().sort"

But when I write

```
series.getData().sort(Comparator.comparingDouble(d -> d.getYValue().doubleValue()));
```

it said that can't resolve method `getYValue`;
How to solve this problem ?

Comment: Probably you used the raw type in the declaration of `series`. BTW: you don't need to sort the list to find the max. You could use the `max` method of the stream api: `series.getData().stream().max(Comparator.comparing(XYChart.Data::getYValue)).orElse(null)`

Comment: it seems that there were something wrong with "XYChart.Data::getYValue",it said non-static method can't be referenced from a static context, and what do you mean  I use raw type in the declaration of "series"?            
        
        XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();

Comment: `XYChart.Series` is a generic class but you don't specify the generic parameters. See [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unlikely that you want to *sort* the data, which would likely distort the chart's meaning. Instead, get a stream of data from the desired series and invoke the [`max()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#max-java.util.Comparator-) method, as @fabian [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53866507/in-javafx-xyseries-find-maximum-y#comment94581046_53866507).

Using data from [`ensemble.samples.charts.line.chart.LineChartApp`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u40/rt/file/2c8e07ca29f3/apps/samples/Ensemble8/src/samples/java/ensemble/samples/charts/line/chart/LineChartApp.java) as an example,

```
ObservableList<XYChart.Series<Double, Double>> lineChartData = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
    new LineChart.Series<>("Series 1", FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        new XYChart.Data<>(0.0, 1.0),
        new XYChart.Data<>(1.2, 1.4),
        new XYChart.Data<>(2.2, 1.9),
        new XYChart.Data<>(2.7, 2.3), //max
        new XYChart.Data<>(2.9, 0.5))),
    new LineChart.Series<>("Series 2", FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        new XYChart.Data<>(0.0, 1.6),
        new XYChart.Data<>(0.8, 0.4),
        new XYChart.Data<>(1.4, 2.9), //max
        new XYChart.Data<>(2.1, 1.3),
        new XYChart.Data<>(2.6, 0.9)))
    );
```

The following fragment produces the expected output [`forEach()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) series.

```
lineChartData.forEach((series) -> {
    System.out.println(series.getData().stream().max(
        Comparator.comparing(XYChart.Data::getYValue)).get().getYValue());
});
```

Console:

```
2.3
2.9
```